# How to reduce my android apk size..?

Tags: android, image, size

I have used lots of images in my android application and now my application size is too big. How can I reduce my android app size without deleting the images

Comment: try reducing the size of your images. Try [this](https://tinypng.com/) for reducing size of PNG images.

Comment: Or maybe try working with Expansion files :
http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Comment: "application size is too big" : How big is too big?

Answer (score 2):

Some advices that might be helpful:

- Take advantage of xml drawables ([reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)), whenever possible.
- Use SVG graphics, if possible. Vector graphics is usually smaller than bitmap graphics. And it will allow to use a single image **for all resolutions**, due to its **intrinsic scalability**. You will need a small 3rd party library, like [androidsvg](https://code.google.com/p/androidsvg/) or similar ones.
- Use 9 patches ([tutorial](http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/)) when you can, and you will save a lot of (normally wasted) pixels in your backgrounds.
- Shrink your PNGs with a tool like [OptiPNG](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/) or similar. They shrink your graphics preserving quality.

And more:

- Remove any debug info.
- Avoid duplicated code.